# Merge Perl hashes into one array and loop through it

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I'm creating a Perl plugin for cPanel which has to get all domains in the account of a user and display it in a HTML `select` field. Originally, I'm a PHP developer, so I'm having a hard time understanding some of the logic of Perl. I do know that cPanel plugins can also be written in PHP, but for this plugin I'm limited to Perl.

This is how I get the data from cPanel:

```
my @user_domains = $cpliveapi->uapi('DomainInfo', 'list_domains');
@user_domains = $user_domains[0]{cpanelresult}{result}{data};
```

This is what it looks like using `print Dumper @user_domains`:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'addon_domains' => ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com'],
    'parked_domains' => ['parked1.com', 'parked2.com', 'parked3.com'],
    'main_domain' => 'main-domain.com',
    'sub_domains' => ['sub1.main-domain.com', 'sub2.main-domain.com']
};
```

I want the data to look like this (thanks @simbabque):

`@domains = qw(domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com main-domain.com parked1.com parked2.com parked3.com);`

So, I want to exclude `sub_domains` and merge the others in 1 single-dimensional array so I can loop through them with a single loop. I've struggled the past few days with what sounds like an extremely simple task, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an example of the target data structure. I think what you want is `@domains = qw( domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com main-domain.com parked1.com parked2.com parked3.com)`

Comment: What did you try so far? Also, is it ok that the type of values is not uniform? I see both scalar values as for `main_domain`, and array references (`addon_domains`, `parked_domains` and `sub_domains`)

Comment: In addition to that, your `@user_domains` is an array that has one element. That element is a hash reference. As @larsen says, one of those elements has a scalar value, the other three have array references. That might be one of the reasons you have so far failed to get stuff to work.

Comment: @larsen so far I've tried using `for` loops like this: `for my $key (keys %$hashref) { }` and then use `Dumper` to see what `$key` holds. The target data should consist of a list with only scalar values, no arrays.

Comment: It's far from clear what the data you get from cPanel looks like.

Comment: @Borodin I understand, updated my question to clear things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

If you find you have a copy of `List::Util` that doesn't include `uniq` then you can either upgrade the module or use this definition

```
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @_;
}
```

From your dump, the `uapi` call is returning a *reference to a hash*. That goes into `$cp_response` and then drilling down into the structure fetches the `data` hash reference into `$data`

`delete` removes the subdomain information from the hash.

The lists you want are the *values* of the hash to which `$data` refers, so I extract those. Those values are *references to arrays* of strings if there is more than one domain in the list, or simple strings if there is only one

The `map` converts all the domain names to a single list by dereferencing array references, or passing strings straight through. That is what the `ref() ? @$_ : $_` is doing. FInally `uniq` removes multiple occurrences of the same name

```
use List::Util 'uniq';

my $cp_response = $cpliveapi->uapi('DomainInfo', 'list_domains');
my $data        = $cp_response->{cpanelresult}{result}{data};

delete $data->{sub_domains};

my @domains = uniq map { ref() ? @$_ : $_ } values %$data;
```

#### output

```
parked1.com
parked2.com
parked3.com
domain1.com
domain2.com
domain3.com
main-domain.com
```

Comment: Damn dude, that instantly did the trick, although it should exclude the `sub_domains`. Can you explain what on earth is happening?

Comment: @SomeCode: I've added an explanation and removed the subdomain data from the result

Answer (score 1):

That isn't doing what you think it' doing. `{}` is the anonymous hash constructor, so you're making a 1 element array, with a hash in it.

You probably want:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %user_domains = (
    'addon_domains' => ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com'],
    'parked_domains' => ['parked1.com', 'parked2.com', 'parked3.com'],
    'main_domain' => 'main-domain.com',
    'sub_domains' => ['sub1.main-domain.com', 'sub2.main-domain.com'],
);

print Dumper \%user_domains;
```

And at which point the 'other' array elements you can iterate through either a double loop:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %user_domains ) { 
    if ( not ref $user_domains{$key} ) { 
        print $user_domains{$key},"\n";
        next;
    }
    foreach my $domain (  @{$user_domains{$key}} ) {
        print $domain,"\n";
    }
}
```

Or if you really want to 'flatten' your hash:

```
my @flatten = map { ref $_ : @$_ ? $_ } values %user_domains;
print Dumper \@flatten;
```

(You need the `ref` test, because without it, the non-array `main-domain` won't work properly)

So for the sake of consistency, you might be better off with:

```
my %user_domains = (
    'addon_domains' => ['domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com'],
    'parked_domains' => ['parked1.com', 'parked2.com', 'parked3.com'],
    'main_domain' => ['main-domain.com'],
    'sub_domains' => ['sub1.main-domain.com', 'sub2.main-domain.com'],
);
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that when I get the domains from cPanel, it has the `{ }` around the data by default. See my updated answer for how I get the data from cPanel.